# Analytics API for Vimeo

Tags: analytics, vimeo-api

We have a video library uploaded on youtube, vimeo and some 2 more other companies and we want to have a way of generating some sort of overview for the aggregated views of this content.

While I know that Youtube provides a REST endpoint that allows you to dig into their analytics, I am not able to find something simmilar from Vimeo. 
So, my question is this: can I programmatically get a dataset from Vimeo with information like number of views/comments/subscribes per day/month/year?

Regards and thanks in advance,
Kay

Answer (score 1):

[edit] I have kept the old comment for historical purposes, but we are not currently accepting beta applicants for the advanced stats endpoints.

A early, limited set of Vimeo's advanced stats are available in their new (in beta) API3. If you would like early access, please contact them at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: Hi Dashron, I would like to know if the api stats are out of beta now. If they are, would you mind sending me a link. Thanks @dashron

Comment: As we continue to roll out the new stats system on vimeo.com, we are going to monitor it's stability and usability. Once the roll out is complete, we will prepare the public release, and start accepting beta participants again.

Comment: But they cannot be in Beta for 2 years right? I mean is that a low priority?

Comment: It's not a low priority, the beta mentioned above was for the advanced stats system we are currently phasing out. The new system offers many more features, and would have included breaking changes to the old system. Instead of forcing users to upgrade, we chose to delay the launch until the new system is in place.